# Newbie C++ question closed for a bad reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, opinion-based

The recent question

[C++ Classes should I use this-> in the .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062377/c-classes-should-i-use-this-in-the-cpp-file)

was closed as opinion-based -- but both alternatives OP provided are objectively wrong, given the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code provided.

The (clearly stylistic and opinion-based) question of whether to use `this->` or not is irrelevant, because *the example given is a constructor*.

Nonstatic data member variables in constructors, especially the kind used in the example, should be initialized with member initializers

```
A a(): i(1)
{
   // initializers do everything
}
```

or better yet, a default member initializer in the class definition:

```
class A
{
   int i = 1;
public:
   A() noexcept = default;
};
```

OP didn't provide a more complicated data member that might require initialization in the constructor body, so the more general case is beside the point.

It wouldn't surprise me if someone found a *duplicate* of this question, but it's **not** opinion-based.  The answer to this question (as asked in the title) with this code is **no**.

Comment: "was closed as opinion-based -- but both alternatives OP provided are objectively wrong, given the c++ code provided." - so? It doesn't matter the way it's phrased. It asks for a comparison of "which is better". If a third, fourth, or Nth option is introduced, it's **still** opinion based, because it asks for preference.

Comment: The same question could have been asked with a regular member function as the example instead of a constructor. So it doesn’t even matter that there’s a third option.

Comment: To `this`, or not to `this`? That is the question—Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of in-body assignment, Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, And, with an intitializer list, end them?

Comment: A Tale of two Styles )

Comment: @user4581301 Off with your overhead.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any clear effort to make it [a _constructive_ subjective question](/help/dont-ask). Though it's really hard to blame them, since someone who doesn't know the language very well probably doesn't know enough to ask about specific pros and cons. Maybe an SME could ask it better or edit it to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

From two options: OP knew exactly what they wanted to ask and worked to have simplest possible example vs. OP did not even know what they are asking about and randomly selected title, I'd pick the first interpretation. As a result, to me this is an opinion-based question with a carefully crafted MRE (for "should I use `this ->`"), but unfortunately the MRE happen to *also* demonstrate the unrelated question "should I unconditionally use field initialization syntax?".

Note that there is nothing wrong with *some* opinion-based close cases—sometimes (like "use `this->` or not in member methods") they just happen to be equally valid without any glaring drawbacks, thus ending up a style choice. It is hard for a novice in a given language/tech to know that in advance (possibly worth a downvote for lack of research in some cases, but this one at least shows a sensible MRE).

If one feels strongly, there are two options to improve the question:

- update the MRE to use a method instead of constructor
- rewrite the post to ask about field initialization